# What's the difference between array.sort() and array.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b; })?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code which triggers some actions. Before that it simply sorts weights. Everything works well when I use: `weight.sort()` where `weight` is an non-empty array e.g. `[10 20 30 40]`, but when I change that to:

```
weight.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

one of the actions has no effect (display a div). Being honest I don't know what might cause the difference. It seems strange to me because `weight` is the same after sorting with both methods and clearly changing that piece of code makes my script working or not. There are no errors in FireBug.

Comment: Here's a helpful link; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
weight = weight.sort
```

the items are sorted by using lexicographical comparison. `=> 2 > 10`

But when you do

```
weight = weight.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b; });
```

the items are compared as numbers instead of string and list sorted in ascending order. `=> 2 < 10`

Also,

```
weight = weight.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
```

will sort by descending order.

Comment: `return a - b` is not the same as the default sorter. The default sorter does a lexicographical comparison.

Answer (score 1):

We usually use such kind of sort to implement some kind of custom compare. In this case the only difference with just calling `sort` is the order of elements - using the code you show, the array will be sorted in descending order(from big to small values) instead of the typical increasing order.

Note that the no-argument sort would return `b-a` instead of a-b which differs in sign and thus reverses the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.sort` without a custom sorting function sorts items in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

You can define a custom function to sort any type of items, using any of their properties. Just make sure the function returns a negative/positive number or 0 based on your comparison result. For example, to sort objects with `name` properties based on their names, you can use:

```
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

Or to sort the items by their `priority` properties (Number):

```
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.priority - b.priority;
});
```

In your custom sorters, you can compare on as many properties as you like. Also make sure you handle undefined items or item properties gracefully. A fortified sort-by-name example:

```
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aName = a && a.name || "",
        bName = b && b.name || "";
    return aName.localeCompare(bName);
});
```